# Error while file download

Tags: java, excel, download

in my servlet, I am passing a file path using cookies and downloading a file as below

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String b = null;
    Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
    if (cookies != null) {
         for (Cookie cookie : cookies) {
           if (cookie.getName().equals("thecookie")) {
               b = cookie.getValue();
            }
          }
        }

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(b+"/logs.txt"));
    String path = br.readLine();
    br.close();

    File file = new File(path+"/Results.xlsx");
    FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(file);
    ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();

    byte[] outputByte = new byte[4096];
    //copy binary contect to output stream
    while(fileIn.read(outputByte, 0, 4096) != -1)
    {
        out.write(outputByte, 0, 4096);
    }
    fileIn.close();
    out.flush();
    out.close();
}
```

Everything works fine and the file is getting downloaded but, I want to download `Results.xlsx` and the file that is being downloaded is `download.zip` and this `download.zip` is same size as my `Results.xlsx` file but is not getting opened by excel.

How do I do this right??

Comment: Don't you use Java 7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're writing the data to the output stream, but you're not setting a content type or a filename. You should use:

```
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Result.xslx");
response.setContentType(
    "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
```

(Before you start writing to the output stream.)

Additionally, your stream-copying loop is broken - you're *always* writing out 4096 bytes even if you haven't read that much. It should be:

```
int bytesRead;
while((bytesRead = fileIn.read(outputByte)) != -1)
{
    out.write(outputByte, 0, byteRead);
}
```

... and you should use a try-with-resources or finally block to make sure you close your stream even if there's an exception.

(Or use a utility method from a library such as Guava.)

Comment: ... Or just use `Files.copy()` ;)

Comment: @Zedai: Did you typo `xslx` for `xlsx`?